# Golang custom type fmt printing

Tags: go, formatting, println, gofmt

I have a custom type like this:

```
type Timestamp struct {
    Time time.Time  
}
// some more methods...
```

Now when I print an instance of it using `fmt`:

```
test := Timestamp{
    Time: time.Now(),
}
fmt.Println("TEST:", test)
```

the output is:

```
TEST: {2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001}
```

How can I add custom formatting to the custom type to pretty print the output like `2009-11-10T23:00:00Z` in cases where it should be printed using `fmt` Functions (`Println` etc..)?

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as adding this function:

```
func (ts Timestamp) Format(f fmt.State, c rune) {
    f.Write([]byte(ts.Time.Format(time.RFC3339)))
}
```

Output:

```
TEST: 2020-05-01T08:25:14Z
```

Comment: A simpler way for most cases is to provide a `String()` method.